# Implementing a Generic Task Scheduler with Nested-Parallelism and Task Dependency support in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

I want to create a generic task scheduler that supports nested parallelism with dependencies, that is, to be able to create and enqueue (child) tasks from inside other (parent) tasks and at the same time the parent task execution be dependent on the child task result. Unfortunately I am having trouble figuring out how to implement this. I am stuck on the following simple case:
Lets assume that we have 2 worker threads and we create/enqueue 2 parent tasks. Each task will start executing on a separate thread. Now each task spawns 2 child tasks and waits for them to finish before returning. But because there are no other available threads (because the two worker threads are blocked waiting the child tasks to finish)  the child tasks will never be executed. As a result the parent tasks will never return.

- One solution I can think of is to just execute all the children tasks serially on the same thread. But this is not efficient because one of the parent tasks and its children might finish very fast and then one thread will be sitting there doing nothing.
- Another solution is to spawn a new thread for every child task. But this might lead to a huge amount of threads and it is not a good idea.
- Another solution would be to enqueue the new children tasks if and only if there threads available. If there aren't then execute the child tasks serially on the same thread with the parent task. This one looks somehow efficient but I am not quit sure if it is correct or how can be implemented.

Is there a standard way/pattern used for the above problem? I also tried to read Intel's TBB documentation on the task scheduler but it is still unclear how TBB is implementing this.

Comment: You can do everything you want with `std::async` and `std::future`s, however, this leaves you with little control over the scheduling guts.  If you want to write your own, leverage `future`s, `promise`s, and `packaged_task`s like `std::async` does. Using `std::async`, after you add a child task and get a future, you will query the future for the result from the child task - at this point if may run in the parent thread if it isn't already being executed in another thread. Either way it will block until the result is ready. A clean solution for the issue you describe.

Comment: Thank you. I do not quite understand though how I can force std::async to run on a particular pool of threads and not spawn a new thread when it is executed asynchronously.

Comment: I guess selecting a particular thread for std::async isn't possible and I will have to use the lower level tools as you said (futures promises etc)

Comment: Think of async as a thread pool with a concurrent queue of tasks. You push on a task, an available thread pops it off and executes it. You have no control over how many threads are in the pool, or any other aspect. I've written my own std:::async-like thing in order to control the number of threads (especially useful to have just 1 thread sometimes) but I can't see why you would want to select a particular thread as the adder of a task.